# How can I delete a single object from a list of objects in One to Many Hibernate Mapping using Criteria API?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-onetomany

I am trying to store details of a user along with his favorite team details also. He can change his favorite team any time.
An user can have several properties, among which he can have multiple Favorite Teams.

Thus, I have made a UserEntity class with a set of FavoriteTeam class as follow (which is obviously one to many mapping)

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="LookupTable",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="favTeamId", referencedColumnName="teamId",unique=true))
private Set<FavouriteTeamEntity> favouriteTeamEntities;
```

---

When someone adds a new favorite team, it works fine. But problem arises when someone removes a team from its list.
Currently i am follow this approach where I am deleting the entire user object along with its child and again reinsert all details except the removed favorite team from the set.

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserEntity.class);
    Root<UserEntity> sRoot = criteriaQuery.from(UserEntity.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(sRoot);    
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(sRoot.get("id"),userID));
    UserEntity i = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).uniqueResult();

    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setEmail(i.getEmail());
    userBean.setId(i.getId());
    userBean.setName(i.getName());

    Set<FavouriteTeam> fSet= new HashSet<>();
    i.getFavouriteTeamEntities().forEach((x) -> {
        FavouriteTeam fTeam = new FavouriteTeam();
        fTeam.setAltCityName(x.getAltCityName());
        fTeam.setCity(x.getCity());
        fTeam.setTeamId(x.getId());
        fTeam.setTricode(x.getTricode());
        fTeam.setFullName(x.getFullName());
        fSet.add(fTeam);
    });
    userBean.setFavouriteTeam(fSet);
    session.delete(i);
    tx.commit();

    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setEmail(userBean.getEmail());
    userEntity.setId(userBean.getId());
    userEntity.setName(userBean.getName());
    session.persist(userEntity);
    tx1.commit();

    userBean.getFavouriteTeam().forEach((fff) -> {
        fff.setUserId(signIn.getId());
        if(String.valueOf(fff.getTeamId()).equals(teamId)) {
            continue;
        }else {
            this.insertTeamAsFavoriteTeam(fff);
        }

    });
    session.close();
```

---

My insertTeamAsFavoriteTeam is as follows :

```
    public String insertTeamAsFavoriteTeam(FavouriteTeam favouriteTeam) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) session.get(UserEntity.class, USER_ID);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    if (userEntity != null) {
        Set<FavouriteTeamEntity> lEntities = sEntity.getFavouriteTeamEntities();
        FavouriteTeamEntity favouriteTeamEntity = new FavouriteTeamEntity();
        favouriteTeamEntity.setId(favouriteTeam.getTeamId());
        favouriteTeamEntity.setAltCityName(favouriteTeam.getAltCityName());
        favouriteTeamEntity.setCity(favouriteTeam.getCity());
        favouriteTeamEntity.setFullName(favouriteTeam.getFullName());
        favouriteTeamEntity.setTricode(favouriteTeam.getTricode());
        lEntities.add(favouriteTeamEntity);
        userEntity.setFavouriteTeamEntities(lEntities);
    }
    session.save(userEntity);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

---

I Know my approach is wrong but as a work around I have use this approach. If anyone has some good approach please share. 
And also I am facing  issue when I delete a user, corresponding its favorite team in favorite Team table gets deleted, which I don't want. I want to delete a particular team from the set or the lookup table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To remove a favorite team from the list... just do that: remove the favorite team from the list. For example: `user.getFavoriteTeams().removeIf(team -> team.id.equals(idToRemove));`. To avoid deleting teams when you delete a use, remove the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` from your annotation. That what cascading does: you do something on the user, and it does the same thing on the linked favorite teams.

Comment: okay i got it with the CascadeType.ALL part but I don't think removing the team from list will actually remove the team from the lookup table

Comment: i want favTeam to be delete from lookup table - which means mapping between a user and this team should get removed rest all remain same

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I already understood it before writing my previous comment.

Comment: so please help me with a nice solution. above written code is not upto the standard

Comment: *I don't think removing the team from list will actually remove the team from the lookup table*: it will. Why do you ask questions if you think you know better than the people answering you? Why don't you at least test it?

Comment: can you share the code, as I have tried that thing didn't worked. That's why I told. No offense.. Please share the code..

Comment: I already shared the code. Open a transaction, find the user, remove the favorite team using the code I posted in my very first comment, then commit the transaction. If you think you did that, then post what you tried.